# How to fix space between two consecutive equations

Tags: spacing, equations

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a+b&=c\\
d+e&=f
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

In this, I need to fix the space between two equations should be as 20pts base to base. Is this possible to fix throughout? Please advise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\\[2ex]` or `\\[4ex]` etc... Or if you would like to set a specific part of the document (as shown with the second equation). Another approach would be to uncomment line 3 and you will have the space to change throughout all the document.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\setlength{\jot}{4ex}  % Uncomment if you want 
                        % the spacing to change 
                        % throughout all the document.
\begin{document}

Normal \verb|\jot|:
\begin{align}
a+b&=c\\
d+e&=f
\end{align}


Tampered \verb|\jot| for a specific part:
{\setlength{\jot}{4ex}% Need this!
\begin{align}
a+b&=c\\
d+e&=f
\end{align}
}

Normal \verb|\jot|:
\begin{align}
a+b&=c\\
d+e&=f
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a fixed space by auto without giving the value [4ex] etc.?

Comment: I did update the answer, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot...